# format the column (date) in an dataset

Tags: c#

i have an dataset  with an column name as  **DATE** it contains an value in this format
1/5/2010(month/day/year).

Now  i need to change the data been displayed(format).
**05-01-2010**

any help how  to  solve this issue  would  be great.

Answer (score 1):

Set the dataformatstring of the bound column to: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}"

EDIT: for some reason I assumed you were binding to a grid, in any event, that format specifier will work if you do `yourDateTimeVariable.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is fixed, but you might have to set HtmlEncode=false on that bound field, thats a notorious old bug

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it to `DateTime` and then back to required string. Hope this helps.

```
 DateTime d=DateTime.Parse("11/01/2005");    
 MessageBox.Show(d.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

Tested :)